# Cant understand why doesnt my telegram bot delete message

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Made bot with node-telegram-bot-api.
My bot has next function, that reacts to some word and with some chance sends a picture as reply,
it must delete this message with picture in several seconds, but it doesnt.

Cant understand why doesnt bot delete this message after sending it.

```
if (lowCaseWords.includes('someWord')) { 
  const randomNumber = Math.random(); 
  if (randomNumber < 0.1) { 
    bot.sendPhoto(chatId,
      'https:...',
      { 
        caption: `text`, 
        parse_mode: 'HTML'
      })
      .then((m) => { 
        setTimeout(() => { 
          bot.deleteMessage(chatId, m.message_id)
          }, deleteTimer)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
   }
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. please format your code

Comment: There is still a `,` missing before `deleteTimer`

Comment: Sorry. Transfered it wrong, now looks like in project.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I shoud add that the code worked when i tested it locally, but after i moved it to remote server this function stopped working.

Comment: Yea you should mention that. But I've voted to close this as 'Not reproducible' as the current code is working fine.